# How to create multiple columns from a column in data frame and cbind() to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, bit-manipulation

I have a column in a dataframe consisting of a 8 bit bitmask.  I want to 'explode' this to 8 new columns in my data frame. The bitmask is defined as:

```
mask <- c('term1'=1,'term2'=2,'term3'=4,'term4'=8,...) #etc
```

by the end, I want 8 new columns in my dataframe named term1 through term8 with a TRUE/FALSE value noting whether the bit was set.  For example, with a 3 bit mask:

```
id   bitmask
 a         1
 b         4
 c         5
```

would be come:

```
id   bitmask   term1   term2   term3
 a         1    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
 b         4   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
 c         5    TRUE    FALSE    TRUE
```

I've gotten as far as writing the function that creates the bitmask column values:

```
addl <- as.data.frame(sapply(data$bitmask, function(x) bitwAnd(x,mask) > 0))
```

But I'm obviously doing something wrong because when I try to see the result using head(addl) it just hangs.  I haven't even gotten to the point of cbind() or setting the column names.  Any help understanding what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try using `:=` to create new columns

Comment: Gary, thank you for the suggestion.  I feel a bit silly asking this, but I looked up operators in R and I didn't see := anywhere.  ?:= from RStudio yielded nothing as well?

Comment: It is from `data.table` package. And I think it is better to use `??":="` to search about this function (if `data.table` is already installed).

Comment: I take back what I said. See below.

Comment: you can pass parameters to your function `FUN` in `sapply` by passing them as parameters in the same function call as a parameter in `sapply`

Comment: Is the result for line `c` correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, set up the data:

```
mask <- c('term1'=1,'term2'=2,'term3'=4)
df <- data.frame(id = c(letters[1:3]), bitmask = c(1,4,5))

cbind(df, sapply(mask, bitwAnd, df$bitmask) > 0)

#   id bitmask term1 term2 term3
# 1  a       1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 2  b       4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 3  c       5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or with `data.table` can do:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.frame(df)

data.table(dt, dt[,sapply(mask, bitwAnd, bitmask)] > 0)

#    id bitmask term1 term2 term3
# 1:  a       1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 2:  b       4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 3:  c       5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I get `bitwAnd(5,2) > 0` is `FALSE`

Comment: Gary, thank you for the input for base R.  I noticed base R is quite slow. Is data.table significantly faster?  I'm perhaps overly hesitant about using relatively new packages without Hadley's name at the end.

Comment: @AlexanderDavid  The first version of `data.table` appeared in April 2006. Is it still recent?

Comment: Looks like I was only seeing the most recent version from the Published statistic on cran.

Comment: @AlexanderDavid `data.table` is extremely fast, robust, well maintained and supported. Especially for large data sets it is much faster than `dplyr`. R has thousands of contributors with thousands of outstanding packages, so while Hadley has authored a number of the "top ten" packages, I would encourage you to explore others without his name, too.

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
mask <- c('term1'=1,'term2'=2,'term3'=4,'term4'=8)

dat <- data.frame(id=letters[1:3], bitmask=c(1, 4, 5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

cbind(dat, do.call(rbind, lapply(dat$bitmask, function(x) {
  setNames(rbind.data.frame(bitwAnd(x, mask)>0), names(mask))
})))

##   id bitmask term1 term2 term3 term4
## 1  a       1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 2  b       4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## 3  c       5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

But Gary's updated answer is way better.

Comment: Thank you!  I cannot install any additional packages in my vdi unfortunately, so this takes the cake.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr, I guess you win anyway. `do.call` is also beautiful in its own way